# 80 Males, 30 Females; How many groups of 3 can be formed such that there is Male and 2 Females in each group.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 80 Males, 30 Females; how many groups of 3 can be formed such that there is 1 Male and 2 Female in each group? **(After forming a group, the members return back for the next group selection)**

Comment: Do you know what a binomial coefficient is? Like $5\choose 3$ or $5C3$ or "$5$ choose $3$"? Because all you need is to know they are to answer your question.

Comment: I didn't until now. I'm having a read online about it. (P.S. I'm in grade 6)
But still, how does that answer the question about "how many groups can be formed?"  All they answer is how many ways in which groups can be formed. Do I need to take a summation of the binomial coefficients?
P.P.S I'm referring to the case when members DO NOT return back for the next group selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\binom{80}{1}\times\binom{30}{2}=34800$$
i.e Number of ways to chose one man from 80 times number of ways to choose two women form 30 women

**Edit: If Members didn't return back**

If members didn't return back then that would mean that the pool to choose form gets smaller with each turn.

1. On first turn there are 
   $$\binom{80}{1}\times\binom{30}{2}=34800$$
2. Now if the the chosen group is taken out next group can be chosen in 
   $$\binom{79}{1}\times\binom{28}{2}=29862$$
3. You can do this $15$ times after doing it $k^th$ time such that $1 \le k \le 15$. The number of ways is 
   $$\binom{81-k}{1}\times\binom{32-2k}{2}=(81-k)(16-k)(31-2k)$$

**Edit2: If you want to know number of ways to make 15 such groups.**

Say the $n^{th}$ group can be chosen in $k_n$ ways, and $1 \le n \le 15$. Then total number of ways is $$Total = \frac{1}{15!}(k_1k_2..k_{15})$$
You have to divide it by $15!$ because the order in which the groups are chosen doesn't matter. And you know how to calculate $k_n$ from above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What if the members did not return back for the next group selection? How would the answer change then?

Comment: Hi, @Rohan, I believe, you were meaning to write 30-2k instead of 32-k? Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Rohan, How does that answer the question about "how many groups can be formed?" All they answer is how many ways in which groups can be formed. Do I need to take a summation of the binomial coefficients?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, @Shawn_Arthur. It is actually the number of groups formed which equals $$\binom {81-k}{1}\binom{32-2k}{2} $$